# How to find the longest pattern of numerics using TSql

Tags: t-sql

I have say a table with as under

```
Values
--------
12Null345XXX23456
6712356

Expected Output
----------------
23456
123
```

How can I do this using TSql(prefereable set based) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want the longest substring of consecutive numeric digits?  Maybe something like this (t here is recreating your original table; if it already exists, skip that CTE and use your table)?:

```
;with ten as (
select i from (values (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) x(i)
), subs as (
select SUBSTRING('0123456789',s.i,l.i) as sub, l.i as run
from ten as s
join ten as l on s.i+l.i<=11
), t as (
select s
from (
values ('12Null345XXX23456'),('6712356'))x(s)
)
select x.sub  
from t
cross apply (select top 1 subs.sub 
             from subs 
             where CHARINDEX(subs.sub,t.s)>0 
             order by subs.run desc) x
```